# putty plink -batch where the command has a semicolon as part of the parameters

Tags: putty, plink

I am trying to do the following:

```
plink -batch <user>@<server> <command> <parameter>
```

The parameter contains a semicolon ; like param="IP1;IP2"

The return says:

> bash: IP2: command not found

I tried to look for a way to set ; delimiter off, so it was not expecting multiple commands.

Comment: And if you do `command IP1;IP2` in shell, don't you get the same error? => We need [mcve], not the vague information you have posted.

Comment: Use backslash (`\;`). Unlike ssh-ing from Unix where the source shell might swallow it, Windows CMD and plink will send backslash to the server, and bash on the server will parse it as quoting (or escaping) the semicolon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following [dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68441769/putty-plink-batch-and-the-command-is-having-a-semicolen-as-part-of-command-pa/68453058#comment120958105_68441769):

> Use backslash (`\;`). Unlike ssh-ing from Unix where the source shell might swallow it, Windows CMD and plink will send backslash to the server, and bash on the server will parse it as quoting (or escaping) the semicolon

I changed it to

```
plink -batch user@server command parameter\\;Parameter_continued
```

which solved the problem.